# can two Java Entities that have "Has a" relationship use the same table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables A and B:

```
@Entity
public class A {
}

@Entity
public class B {
    private final A a;
    private String someBSpecificField;
}
```

Entity A is already Coded nicely and mapped to an existing table. My job is to create B and for some reason I prefer composition over inheritance between A and B. At the same time I want to have single table for A and B to avoid joins when reading. Can I do like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "a_type_enum", discriminatorType = 
   DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("100")
 public class A {
 }
    
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "a")
  @DiscriminatorValue("500")
  public class B {
      private final A a;
      private String someBSpecificField;
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on "I want to have single table for A and B to avoid joins when reading"?

Answer (score 2):

If  the type is a complex object then you need to annotate that type with `@Embeddable` and use it in your `@Entity` class.

if you want to override the attribute names for your `@Embeddable` class so they have different column names, you can do so with the `@AttributeOverrides` annotation.

Comment: Entity A is not Embeddable, It is annotated with @Entity, do you mean I can Embedd a full fledged Entity without annotating it @Embeddable?

Comment: Annotate class B @Embeddable. and embed it in your Entity class